# Programmable Logic devices can be used as replacement to logic gates and MSI chips?

Tags: digital-logic

Programmable Logic devices can be used as replacement to logic gates and MSI chips ? how these devices can have an effect on the performance of storage fundamentals, which will give better performance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Logic Versus Programmable Logic Logic devices can be classified into two broad categories - fixed and programmable. As the name suggests, the circuits in a fixed logic device are permanent, they perform one function or set of functions - once manufactured, they cannot be changed. On the other hand, programmable logic devices (PLDs) are standard, off-the-shelf parts that offer customers a wide range of logic capacity, features, speed, and voltage characteristics - and these devices can be changed at any time to perform any number of functions. With fixed logic devices, the time required to go from design, to prototypes, to a final manufacturing run can take from several months to more than a year, depending on the complexity of the device. And, if the device does not work properly, or if the requirements change, a new design must be developed. The up-front work of designing and verifying fixed logic devices involves substantial "non-recurring engineering" costs, or NRE. NRE repres